# Autoconf uses wrong AR on OS X

Tags: autotools, autoconf, unix-ar

I'm testing on OS X. We have a `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am`. Autotools is selecting the wrong `AR` and `ARFLAGS` for the platform. It happens with (and without) `AM_PROG_AR` in `Makefile.am`:

```
$ egrep 'AR =|ARFLAGS =' Makefile
AMTAR = $${TAR-tar}
AR = ar
ac_ct_AR = ar
```

Autoconf should be using Apple's `libtool` (not to be confused Autotools' `libtool`) and `libtool`'s flags. Apple's `libtool` properly handles fat libraries and cross-compiles. It should be [something like](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile#L467):

```
AR = /usr/bin/libtool
ARFLAGS = -static -o
```

Apple's [Porting UNIX/Linux Applications to OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/compiling/compiling.html) does not discuss the topic, and I can't find it searching the Autoconf documentation. The Autoconf docs also lacks a `AC_PROG_AR` (or similar). See [5.2.1 Particular Program Checks](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Particular-Programs.html) in the Autoconf manual.

How do we tell Autoconf to use Apple's platform build tools, and not the Linux build tools?

---

```
$ autoconf --version
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69

$ automake --version
automake (GNU automake) 1.15.1
```

Comment: Are you using [`AM_PROG_AR`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#index-AM_005fPROG_005fAR) in `configure.ac`?

Comment: I think you will need to specify your preferred options on the configure command line: `./configure AR=/usr/bin/libtool ARFLAGS="-static -o"`.  There's then a chance that you'll override what the script would determine for itself.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Running `AR=/usr/bin/libtool ARFLAGS='-static -o' ./configure` dies early. The message is *`checking the archiver (/usr/bin/libtool) interface... unknown`* and then *`configure: error: could not determine /usr/bin/libtool interface`*. That's kind of why we've been trying to fix it in the script.

Comment: Still occurs in February 2019 when installing OpenFST on MacOS Mojave. Any solution?

Answer (score 5):

> Autotools is selecting the wrong `AR` and `ARFLAGS` for the platform. It happens with (and without) `AM_PROG_AR` in `Makefile.am`: [...] Autoconf should be using Apple's `libtool`

I understand that you *would like* `configure` to select and use OS X `libtool` for creating archives, and that doing so would afford you some advantages.  POSIX `ar` may even be an unsuitable tool for your particular job, but I reject the assertion that `/usr/bin/ar` is the wrong tool *for the platform*.  Apple provides that tool in OS X, and it works as advertised, even if the advertised behavior is more circumscribed than you want or need.

> It should be something like:
>
> ```
> AR = /usr/bin/libtool
> ARFLAGS = -static -o
> ```

Maybe.  Although Mac `libtool` can perform the same function as `ar`, it is not a drop-in replacement.  That's what `configure` complains about when you specify those variables on its command line (but only when you also have `AM_PROG_AR`).  In particular, if you examine the `configure` script you will probably find that it tests the behavior of the tool designated by `AR` with use of a command such as this:

```
$AR cru libconftest.a conftest.$ac_objext >&5
```

It will also have a fallback for the interface provided by Microsoft's `lib` utility.  Both of these are associated with the `AM_PROG_AR` macro.

Note that the test uses hardcoded flags for the main options, not any `$ARFLAGS` that may have been specified.  It is specifically testing the program's command-line interface, and Mac `libtool` does not provide one that is recognized.

You have several options:

- Let the build system continue to use `AM_PROG_AR`, and provide a wrapper script for Mac `libtool` that mimics the traditional command-line interface of POSIX `ar`.  When configuring for Mac, designate the wrapper script to `configure` as the value of variable `AR`.

  ```
  ./configure AR=my-mac-libtool-wrapper
  ```
- If the build system *does not* use `AM_PROG_AR` then by default the `AR` and `ARFLAGS` variables will mean nothing to `configure`, but you can specify them directly to `make`:

  ```
  make AR=/usr/bin/libtool ARFLAGS="-static -o"
  ```
- Alternatively, if the build system does not use `AM_PROG_AR` then you can add your own code to make `configure` handle the `AR` and `ARFLAGS` variables.  The minimum to get `configure` to recognize them and pass them on to the Makefile without performing any actual tests would probably be:

  ```
  AC_ARG_VAR([AR], [Specifies the archiver to use])
  AC_ARG_VAR([ARFLAGS], [Specifies the archiver flags to use])
  ```

Comment: Thanks John. *"I understand that you would like configure to select and use OS X libtool..."* - I believe its a bit stronger than that. Apple advises it, and the `ar(1)` utility does not handle fat files. I'll try some of your suggestions. Thanks again.